# ¿Por qué el bucle es infinito en el manejo de excepciones?

Tags: java, excepciones, bucles

¡Buenas comunidad!, estoy estudiando manejo de excepciones con algunos ejemplos sencillos. La idea es que haya una persistencia en el ingreso de datos hasta que el usuario ingrese los datos adecuados, sólo estoy considerando dos catch: Para división entre cero y el caso en el que no introduce un número.

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Excepciones {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        boolean bandera = true;
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);


        do {

            try {
                System.out.println("Introduce el numerador:");
                double numerador = entrada.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Introduce el denominador:");
                double denominador = entrada.nextDouble();
                System.out.println(numerador/denominador);
                bandera = false;
            } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
                System.out.println("NO puedes dividir entre cero, ¡LOL!");
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Introduce números, no cosas raras, ¡LOL!");
            }

        }while(bandera);

    }


}
```

NO obstante, cuando se ingresan ceros o no números, manda el mensaje del catch, pero infinitas veces, no da oportunidad a que el usuario vuelva a meter los datos.

¿Alguna idea del porqué sucede esto?

¡Muchas gracias por adelantado!

Answer (score 6):

Tomado de la documentación:

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace. The resulting tokens may then be converted into values of different types using the various next methods.
>   ...
>   When a scanner throws an InputMismatchException, the scanner will not pass the token that caused the exception, so that it may be retrieved or skipped via some other method.

Traducción mia:

> La clase `scanner` divide la entrada en *palabras*, por defecto separadas por espacios en blanco. Las distintas *palabras* pueden ser extraidas llamando a los distintos métodos `nextXXX`.
>   Cuando se produce una excepción `InputMismatchException`, la *palabra* **no es extraida**; debe ser omitida o limpiada por algún otro método.

Pues ya sabemos tu problema. Al producirse una excepción, la *palabra* queda a la espera de ser extraida. Tú no lo haces, sino que al continuar el bucle, vuelves a intentar extraerla, con lo que se vuelve a lanzar otra excepción, que te lleva al inicio del bucle, donde vuelves a intentar extraer la misma palabra, ...

Deberías extraerla en tu controlador de excepciones:

```
try {
  System.out.println("Introduce el numerador:");
  double numerador = entrada.nextDouble();
  System.out.println("Introduce el denominador:");
  double denominador = entrada.nextDouble();
  System.out.println(numerador/denominador);
  bandera = false;
} catch (ArithmeticException e) {
  System.out.println("NO puedes dividir entre cero, ¡LOL!");
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
  System.out.println("Introduce números, no cosas raras, ¡LOL!");
  entrada.next( );
}
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias amigo!, saludos.